# Stop YouTube yt-player with class instead of id

Tags: jquery, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I am embedding multiple YouTube videos using JQuery based on user's selections.

```
$('#content_frame_right').on('click', '#video_respiratory_exam', function(){
            $('#content_frame_left').html("<div id='yt-player'><iframe width='380' height='285' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/EEjIThphoig?enablejsapi=1&autoplay=1' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe></div>");
    });
```

I am needing to stop all the videos based on the object's class, instead of the id, 'yt-player'.  However the API requires 'yt-player' to be object ID:

```
callPlayer('yt-player', 'stopVideo');
```

Having the same ID on multiple objects results in inconsistent behaviour. Is there a way to stop all videos with a class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a class to retreive the uniques ids like this:

```
$(".yt-player").each(function(){
    var thisPlayerID = $(this).attr("id").
    callPlayer(thisPlayerID, 'stopVideo');
});
```

Comment: Louys, what can I say, your my main man (not really, but close)!  Woohhoo!!  Ta very much indeed.  Peter

Comment: Oooh, now I'm 2 points from 1000...the suspense is killing me.

Comment: lollll! ;) I have an issue with `youtube-api` too... If you want to have a look at [my bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823490/javascript-event-listener-quits-from-listening-youtube-api-no-console-e) ;)